# How to determine elements scroll position in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll in my chat widget. I have a `ref` setup for chat body's `container` like this:

```
const containerNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.container)
```

I also already setup an event listener that handle's the scroll:

```
containerNode.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll);
```

I am now trying to find out how to implement the use case where before i can scroll up, it would make an ajax call.

```
handleScroll() {
    console.log("make an ajax call before it scrolls all the way up")
    if (some_conditon){
      //then load more!
    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Note, that there's a new way of creating references to a dom element: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are scrolling up to the top all you need to do is look at the scroll top of your container.

```
const offset = 100 // 100 px before the request
if (containerNode.scrollTop < offset) {
    // request more here
}
```

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jwm6k66c/2480/)